# TFS Save Changes Private & Undo Pending Changes

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I inherited a huge c# project, I am planning to do the following

- Make alot of changes to project files (many files)
- Save all of my changes to tfs privately,so I dont check-in my work and mess up teams work. Reason why I want to save is, so I can refer back to my changes.
- After Saving Changes, I want to overwrite my files with the Latest Version from server. Get Latest wont work,,,since my changes are newer then the server version.

In a Nutshell, I want to change some files for testing, save them as a reference just for myself and then undo my pending changes and overwrite my files with latest version from server.

How can I do above steps using TFS. i am using Visual Studio 2012 if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a "private" branch or use a shelveset. A branch would be more reliable (shelveset could be deleted without leaving a history).

Comment: what about second part of question....how can I get the Latest Files From Server (say when i want to revert to the original code)...I believe I have to "Undo Pending Changes"...and then do a Get Specific?

Comment: Yes. You can either do:
1. Undo pending changes and get latest version
2. Get specific and overwrite any/all local files

Answer (score 3):

This is the canonical use case for a branch. Create a branch for your large-scale change.